# How to register and than search a value in CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to register an user and then read the data I just appended. It looks like the csv file is appending the value, but it's not saving it. But this is awkward, because I used the "with open" function at the "registered" function.

```
def is_registered(ID): #OK
    df = read_any_csv(users_path)
    x = df.loc[df["ID"] == ID]
    if x.empty:
        return False
    else:
        return True

#faz o cadastro do usuario
def register(ID): #OK
        x = str(input("Escreva seu nome:  "))        
        name = x.title()
        section = int(input("Digite seu setor(111/112/113): "))
        data = [name,ID,section]
        with open (users_path,'a') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(data)
def start():
#Se o usuario estiver registrado, da as boas vindas a ele, caso nao, registra ele e depois da as boas vindas
    if is_registered(ID) == True: #OK
        current_user = users_df.loc[users_df["ID"] == ID]
        name = current_user["NAME"]
        name2 =(name.to_string(index=False))
        section = current_user["SECTION"]
        print(f"Ola, {name2}, bem vindo ao programa de treinamento Mercedes Benz Brasil!\n")
        videos = videos_to_watch(section)
        print("Esses sao os videos que faltam serem assistidos:\n")
        print(*videos,sep = '\n')
    else: #OK
        register(ID)
        users_df.to_csv("Users.csv",index = False)    
        current_user = users_df.loc[users_df["ID"] == ID]     
        print(current_user)
```

But the csv can't find the data, the result that I got is that:

```
Digite o ID: aaaaa
Escreva seu nome:  leo
Digite seu setor(111/112/113): 113
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [NAME, ID, SECTION]
Index: []
```

What I actually want is:

```
Digite o ID: 5DBEF04B
Escreva seu nome:  Raul Lopes Camina
Digite seu setor(111/112/113): 113
Ola, Raul Lopes Camina, bem vindo ao programa de treinamento Mercedes Benz Brasil!
```

Comment: you saved in file but now you have to read this file again to get new data in `users_df`. OR you should do `users_df.append(data)` to have it also in dataframe in memory.

Comment: as for me your `with open (users_path,'a') as file` is useless - you should do `users_df.append(data)` and later `users_df.to_csv(...)` will save it in file.

Comment: Still not working, I put read the read_csv right afeter the "with open" in the registered(ID) function

Comment: I changed the `with open` to `users_df.append(data)` and then `users_df.to_csv(users_path,index=False)`. 

But i'm still geting as result:

`Digite o ID: tttttttt

Escreva seu nome:  Saulo

Digite seu setor(111/112/113): 111

d:\Users\raulc\Documents\AMBIENTES\mercedes.py:36: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.  users_df.append(data)

Ola, Series([], ), bem vindo ao programa de treinamento Mercedes Benz Brasil!`

Comment: it is only warning, not error. And it only suggests to use `concat()` instead of `append()`

Comment: see more [Merge, join, concatenate and compare — pandas 1.4.2 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Answer (score 0):

You write new data to file but this can't change original `users_df` and you would have to read it again (instead of write again)

```
    register(ID)

    users_df = pd.read_csv("Users.csv")  # <-- read instead of write

    current_user = users_df.loc[users_df["ID"] == ID]     

    print(current_user)
```

---

Or you should first add to `users_df` and later save it with `to_csv` - and then you don't have to read it again.

```
def register(ID):  # OK
    global users_df  # need it to add to external variable
    
    name = str(input("Escreva seu nome:  "))        
    name = name.title()
    section = int(input("Digite seu setor(111/112/113): "))

    data = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': [name], 'ID': [ID], 'SECTION': [section]})
    
    users_df = pd.concat([users_df, data])   # <-- add to original `users_df`

    users_df.to_csv("Users.csv", index=False)
```

and later

```
    register(ID)

    # without `to_csv()` and `read_csv()`

    current_user = users_df.loc[users_df["ID"] == ID]     

    print(current_user)
```